# How to change the value of a variable

Tags: python

I'm having a bit of trouble with changing a variable value (canteen) to make it so that it runs from 3 to 0. I'm not sure why the value of canteen does not go to less than 2 every time I hit the "1" key. How do I make it so that the value of canteen becomes zero when the player hits the "1" key 3 times?

```
# Global Variables
km_travelled = 0
thirst = 0
camel_tiredness = 0
natives_travelled = -20 # Player always starts 20 km away from player once player reaches checkpoint

def introduction():
    print("Welcome to Camel!")
    print("You have stolen a camel to make your way across the great Mobi desert")
    print("The natives want their camel back and are chasing you down! Survive ")
    print("your desert trek and out run the natives \n \n")

def choices():
    print("1. Drink from your canteen.")
    print("2. Ahead at moderate speed.")
    print("3. Ahead at full speed.")
    print("4. Stop for the night.")
    print("5. Status check.")
    print("9. Quit \n")

def questions(answer):
    canteen = 3
    if "9" in answer:
        print("GAME EXIT.")
        done = True
    elif "1" in answer:
        print("You drank from the canteen")
        canteen = canteen - 1
        print(canteen)


def main():
    #  Global variables
    done = False

    # Go through once
    introduction()
    while not done:
        choices()
        answer = input("What is your choice? ")
        questions(answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're defining `canteen = 3` at the beginning of your `questions()` loop. You should define it once, with your global variables.

```py
# Global Variables
km_travelled = 0
thirst = 0
camel_tiredness = 0
natives_travelled = -20 # Player always starts 20 km away from player once player reaches checkpoint
canteen = 3 # Define it here, as a global variable

### Truncated ###

def questions(answer):
    # canteen = 3 # Don't define here
    global canteen # but refer to the top one here
    if "9" in answer:
        print("GAME EXIT.")
        done = True
    elif "1" in answer:
        print("You drank from the canteen")
        canteen = canteen - 1
        print(canteen)


def main():
    #  Global variables
    done = False

    # Go through once
    introduction()
    while not done:
        choices()
        answer = input("What is your choice? ")
        questions(answer)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I edit my answer, I just forgot to add the global declaration

Answer (score 0):

The `canteen` variable is locally scoped, to the `questions` function. And each time you run that function, it is reinitialised to the value 3. Since the `if` statement is only executed once inside the function, it will never go lower than 2.

One simple way to solve this - even though it's not good practice - is to have `canteen` as a global variable. Put `canteen = 3` outside any function, alongside the rest of your globa variables. Remove that statement from the `questions` function, and replace it with `global canteen` so that Python knows you are referring to the global variable when you alter it within the function.

Note that you will have a similar problem with the `done` variable, and can consider making this global too.

And finally, as I hinted at, global variables are bad to have in any program that isn't extremely simple - because they can be affected by everything in the program, and therefore make it very hard to figure out what is going on. There are a number of alternative ways to approach constructing complex programs which avoid global variables, which I would encourage you to look at. Using classes (which hold state internally, rather than globally) is one such way which is well-supported in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Since while statement evaluates to true, the value 3 is assigned to the variable canteen after every choice. You can replace `canteen = 3` with `global canteen` and assign the variable canteen outside it's function.
If you want to avoid using global, you can use a dictionary like this example:

```
def questions(answer, canteen):
    if "9" in answer:
        print("GAME EXIT.")
        done = True
    elif "1" in answer:
        print("You drank from the canteen")
        canteen['c'] = canteen['c'] - 1
        print(canteen['c'])


def main():
    #  Global variables
    done = False
    canteen = {'c': 3}
    # Go through once
    introduction()
    while not done:
        choices()
        answer = input("What is your choice? ")
        questions(answer, canteen)
```